# jquery radio button change not detected by bound function

Tags: jquery, radio-button, detection

With the following html:

```
<input type = "radio" name = "who" class = "number" value = "0" > text </input>
<input type = "radio" name = "who"   class = "number" value = "1" > text </input>
<input type = "radio" name = "numberS"  class = "number"  value = "1" > text </input>
<input type = "radio" name = "numberS"  class = "number"  value = "2" > text</input>
```

and the following two bits of javascript:

```
$('input[class="number"]').bind('change', function (){
    alert("Change!");
    })

function change_radio_button(n){
   $('input[class="number"]')[n].checked = true;
   }
```

As is, this all works perfectly: selecting a new radio button calls the alert, and calling change_radio_button() changes which radio button is selected.

But when change_radio_button() is called and the radio button selection changes, the bound function does not detect the change--the alert doesn't happen. Why not?  Does the jquery function only detect manual changes?

Comment: You are correct - jQuery only detects manual changes. You could separate your function that runs when the radio button is changed and have the change_radio_button function call it.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll guess I'll have to do that!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a class then use class selector. Using `class` as attribute selector is not a best practice.

```
$('input.number').bind('change', function (){
    alert("Change!");
});
```

And you want to fire change event use `trigger` or just call `change()` method. This event will not be changed when you change the check the radio buttons programmatically.

```
function change_radio_button(n){
   $('input.number')[n].checked = true;
   $('input.number').trigger('change');
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with these formats.  I'll fiddle with them.  Thanks.

Comment: Just found this, and `.trigger('change');` was exactly what I needed for my own issue.